# Limit of a sequence using the formal definition

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I want to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \cfrac{3n^2 -n+1}{n-2n^2} = \cfrac{3}{2}$ using the definition of limit of sequences.

So let $\epsilon>0$ and consider $| \frac{3n^2 -n+1}{n-2n^2} -\frac{3}{2}| = |\frac{12n^2-5n+2}{2n-4n^2}| = |\frac{(3n-2)(4n+1)}{(2n)(1-2n)}|$.

We have $ |\frac{(3n-2)(4n+1)}{(2n)(1-2n)}| \le |\frac{4n+1}{2n}| |\frac{3n-2}{1-2n}| \le |\frac{4n+1}{2n}| |\frac{3n}{-2n}| = |\frac{4n+1}{2n}| \frac{3}{2} \dots < \epsilon$.

So is this way correct or what is the correct way to show it?

Comment: Should it be $\frac{-3}{2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not correct, and it could not possibly be correct, since the limit is actually $-\frac32$. Note that$$\frac{3n^2-n+1}{n-2n^2}+\frac32=\frac{-n-2}{4n^2-2n}=-\frac{1+\frac2n}{4n-2}.$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: Where is the $\varepsilon$?

Comment: As it should be obvious from the final question, I just gave you a hint.

Comment: The latter sign must be $+$. After that I wrote $\cfrac{n+2}{4n^2-2n} \le \cfrac{n+2}{(2n-1)^2} \le \cfrac{2n-1}{(2n-1)^2} = \cfrac{1}{2n-1}$ but I am not sure what to do after your step.

Comment: Note that$$\left\lvert-\frac{1+\frac2n}{4n-2}\right\rvert\leqslant\frac1{4n-2}$$and that$$\frac1{4n-2}<\varepsilon\iff n>\frac{\frac1\varepsilon+2}4.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \cfrac{3n^2 -n+1}{n-2n^2}=\cfrac{\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(3 -\dfrac1n+\dfrac1{n^2}\right)}{\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\dfrac1n-2\right)}.$$

Comment: Where is the $\varepsilon$?

Comment: @user658409: some multiple of $\frac1n$ should do.